# How to get fullDocument from MongoDB changeStream when a document is deleted?

Tags: database, mongodb, changestream

### My Code

I have a MongoDB with two collections, `Items` and `Calculations`.

```
Items
  value:  Number
  date:   Date
```

```
Calculations
  calculation:  Number
  start_date:   Date
  end_date:     Date
```

A `Calculation` is a stored calcluation based off of `Item` values for all `Items` in the DB which have dates in between the `Calculation`'s start date and end date.

### Mongo Change Streams

I figure a good way to create / update `Calculations` is to create a Mongo Change Stream on the `Items` collection which listens for changes to the `Items` collection to then recalculate relevant `Calculations`.

The issue is that according to the [Mongo Change Event docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#change-stream-output), when a document is deleted, the `fullDocument` field is omitted which would prevent me from accessing the deleted `Item`'s date which would inform which `Calculations` should be updated.

### Question

Is there any way to access the `fullDocument` of a Mongo Change Event that was fired due to a document deletion?

Comment: if Items/date combination is unique you could make that your primary key (_id) and then it's available no matter what operation is performed on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No I don't believe there is a way. From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#event-notification:

> Change streams only notify on data changes that have persisted to a majority of data-bearing members in the replica set.

When the document was deleted and the deletion was persisted across the majority of the nodes in a replica set, the document has ceased to exist in the replica set. Thus the changestream cannot return something that doesn't exist anymore.

The solution to your question would be [transactions in MongoDB 4.0](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions). That is, you can adjust the `Calculations` and delete the corresponding `Items` in a single atomic operation.

Comment: actually the solution would be to include immutable fields as part of the document key (i.e. the _id).

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Can you clarify what you mean with a link to an example (or by adding your own answer)? Are you suggesting using [`createIndex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/), or manually setting the `_id` field on every `insert`, or something else?

Comment: I mean that if the _id field includes the date as well as whatever item id is, then you'd know which date's calculation needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

`fullDocument` is not returned when a document is deleted.

But there is a workaround.

Right before you delete the document, set a hint field. (Obviously use a name that does not collide with your current properties.)

```js
await myCollection.updateOne({_id:theId}, {_deleting: true})
await myCollection.deleteOne({_id:theId})
```

This will trigger one final `change` event in the stream, with a hint that the document is getting deleted.  Then in your stream watcher, you simple check for this value.

```js
stream.on('change', event => {
  if (!event.fullDocument) {
    // The document was deleted
  }
  else if (event.fullDocument._deleting) {
    // The document is going to be deleted
  }
  else {
   // Document created or updated
  }

})
```

My oplog was not getting updated fast enough, and the update was looking up a document that was already removed, so I needed to add a small delay to get this working.

```js
myCollection.updateOne({_id:theId}, {_deleting: true})
setTimeout( ()=> {
  myCollection.deleteOne({_id:theId})
}, 100)
```

If the document did not exist in the first place, it won't be updated or deleted, so nothing gets triggered.

## Using TTL Indexes

Another way to make this work is to add a ttl index, and then set that field to the current time.  This will trigger an update first, and then delete the document automatically.

```js
myCollection.setIndex({_deleting:1}, {expireAfterSeconds:0})
```

```js
myCollection.updateOne({_id:theId}, {$set:{_deleting:new Date()}})
```

The problem with this approach is that mongo prunes TTL documents only during certain intervals, 60s or more as stated in the docs, so I prefer to use the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

In Mongo v6.0, you are now able to access [pre- and post-operation images of documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/#change-streams-with-document-pre--and-post-images) in change events. You need to enable this on your watched collection *before* you can access the pre-document. Once you do that, you can include it in your options object that you pass to the change stream. For deleted documents, `fullDocumentBeforeChange` is what you're looking for - you access it the same way you access `fullDocument` in the change event currently.